# How to set custome price In App Purchase not set tier price I set manually prices

Tags: swift, in-app-purchase, itunes, in-app

I'm unable to change the price of an in-app purchase. I added initially for testing purposes, but now that I'm submitting the app, I'd like to change it. Unfortunately, it doesn't seem to accept the change. It is showing me the same price tier not the updated one.what should i do ?
I set price Rs.10 or Rs.20 how

Comment: I'm having a hard time understanding the exact issue (both due to language and vagueness). You *must* use App Store Connect to set pricing, not matter if it's pay up front, free, IAP,or  subscription. Also, you *must* choose a tier. I've had no issue choosing a different tier using App Store Connect. So... could you give more specifics?

Comment: Did you submit your app? You can change the price if you did not submit it yet. Delete and create your in app purchase again. But i am sure you can change it because i just did it last week. Maybe you can show some screenshots.

Comment: @YucelBayram I mean price change possible but set dynamic price every product its not possible